# How to type a very long string for testing an input box in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, automated-tests, cypress, rich-text-editor

I want to test the validation for the character limit of a RichTextEditor, which is 2000 characters, but typing 2000+ characters with `.type()` takes a lot of time.

Is there a way to speed this up? I tried with Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v modifiers but it is not copy-pasting the text in the input box.

Comment: [`.type()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type) has a configuration argument that takes an object. One of the configurable options is `delay` which controls the interval between key presses. The default is `10` so setting it to `0` or `1` is likely to speed things up.

Answer (score 15):

The problem with reducing the delay `{ delay: 0 }` is that it's there to throttle the char stream in case some event handler or validation can't handle the highest rate.

Also, if I test with the simplest input, no javascript attached

```html
<input maxlength="2000">
```

the test takes 37 seconds with default delay of 10ms, but is still **24 seconds** with delay of 0.

I would recommend setting 2000 chars via the `val()` method and type the last

```js
cy.get('input')
  .invoke('val', stringGen(2000))  // set 2000 chars
  .type('!')                       // add another
  .invoke('val')                   // read the value
  .should('have.length', 2000)     // confirm the last did not go in
```

This runs in **0.6 seconds**

If you have some javascript event handlers, you would need to trigger them after setting the initial 2000 chars

```
.trigger('change')
```

or

```
.trigger('input')
```

---

### RichTextEditor

A rich text editor using `<div>` to hold the text can be pre-loaded with the `text()` method instead of the `val()` method.

You will also need to identify the div that receives the text.

For example [react-quill](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill) uses the class `ql-editor` on it's primary div.

```js
cy.get('div.ql-editor')
  .invoke('text', stringGen(2000))  // set 2000 chars
  .type('!')                        // add another
  .invoke('text')                   // read the value
  .should('have.length', 2000)      // confirm the last did not go in
```

**Timings for react-quill**

`{ delay: 10 }` (default)  32 seconds
`{ delay: 0 }`             18 seconds
preload the text           1.5 seconds

Comment: Actually, I am using a custom RichTextEditor and it doesn't render input on the DOM, it renders div, so on Div, if I try to invoke 'val' it is not working

Comment: `<div>`s use text nodes to hold the text, so the jQuery method to invoke is not `val` it's `text`.

Comment: What is stringGen?

Answer (score 10):

You can pass options to the type function `type(text, options)`

For available options, you can take a look at the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Arguments)

In your case, you could try to overwrite the `delay` option to remove the input duration.

```
inputField.type('a'.repeat(2000), { delay: 0})
```

Answer (score 2):

if You pu this piece of code to `cypress/support/index.js` file it should remove the delay between the key strokes.

```
Cypress.Keyboard.defaults({
  keystrokeDelay: 0,
})
```

update:
Here is a documentation of Cypress API
[Keyboard Cypress API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/keyboard-api#Syntax)

Comment: Cypress.Keyboard.defaults is not a function- throwing this error

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code ([from this post](https://egghead.io/blog/handling-copy-and-paste-in-cypress)) to quickly copy-paste hundred email adresses in a textarea :

```js
it('pastes text to textarea', () => {
  const textToPaste = 'this is not a valid email'
  cy.visit('index.html')
  cy.get("[type='email']").invoke('val', textToPaste).trigger('blur')
})
```

Based on the [invoke() cypress method](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke#Function)